# C - typedef vs #define

Tags: c, typedef

I read that:

> The C programming language provides a keyword called typedef, which you can use to give a type, a new name. Following is an example to define a term BYTE for one-byte numbers:       typedef unsigned char BYTE;

This can be done using `#define` too. Like:

```
#define BYTE unsigned char
```

So my question is... Why use `typedef` when I can use `#define`?

I mean `#define` can be used for things which are not types too. So what advantage do I get for using `typedef`?

Comment: Imagine a `typedef` for long structure and try to implement it with `#define`.

Comment: TL;DR: One is lexical replacement, the other is seen by the type system. Read the high voted answers in the duplicated post for pitfalls and differences in semantics.